# ASP.NET tooltips

Tags: asp.net

I'm using VS2010,C# to develop my ASP.NET web app, I'm going to display some small and simple tooltips over my objects, I want to be able to set tooltip text from codebehind, what are my options (solutions for all browsers)? how can I find some easy-to-use tooltips with usage tutorials?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many ASP.NET controls contain a settable `ToolTip` property

Comment: thanks but I've seen several sites displaying nice a cool tooltips that seem to be javascript or other client-side staff, how can I use them?

Comment: thanks friends, I think I found my answer! ASP.NET controls have tooltip property, so there is no need to use client-side staff! thanks

Answer (score 1):

Most controls are going to have a ToolTip property on the control that you can set.  I don't know of any issues between browsers.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.tooltip.aspx

Also if you are trying to do anything w/ rich content you might want to check out something like this.

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/tooltip/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx